# Fortran read statement gives no compilation error

Tags: fortran

Why is gfortran not showing any compilation error for the read statement here?

```
program test
    character(len=2) :: x
    read x
end program
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does not issue an error because all individual lines are valid and the error can only be detected at runtime.  You may think that `read` is going to read data from somewhere and store it in `x`, but that is not what is happening.  The statement

```
read x
```

matches R910 in the Fortran 2008 standard (cl 9.6.1).  Specifically, one possibility of *read-stmt* is:

> READ *format* [, *input-item-list*]

which will match `read x`, interpreting `x` as a format.  You can confirm this by running your program, which produces the runtime error:

```
At line 3 of file read.f90 (unit = 5, file = 'stdin')
Fortran runtime error: Missing initial left parenthesis in format
```

Comment: can you give some example string x, for which read x will take it as a valid format string, as i am not familiar with Fortran 2008.

Comment: @user5284834 any valid format will work, `()` is a 2 character one.  These aren't specific to Fortran 2008, they are the same (for the most part) as whatever standard you are targetting with your code.

Answer (score 2):

The code is erroneous, but not in a way that a compiler is required to be able to detect.

`read x` by itself isn't inherently an invalid read statement.  This isn't an attempt to read into the variable `x` but is a read with format given by `x`.  [It's a read statement with no input list.]  As such, the error comes from the fact that (the undefined variable) `x` is not a valid format.

Detecting whether a format is valid when it comes from a variable isn't generally possible at compile time.  If you try to run the program that compiles you may well find that the runtime complains about the invalid format.

Comment: but isn't format string supposed to be in brackets. so when is read x a valid statement.?

Comment: `read x` is valid when `x` is a valid format specification.  Yes, part of being valid is that parentheses are involved.  If you did `character(2) ::x='()'; read x`, for example, that would be perfectly valid.  [All that would happen would be a record would be read from "standard input".]