# Error: Missing leading left parenthesis in format string at (1)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

The program says that there is an error:

> Error: Missing leading left parenthesis in format string at (1)

Could pleas tell me what to do to solve this?

[image: screenshot]

```
program main
    implicit none

    real t, v, h

    print "Escribir tiempo:"

    read*, t

    v = 10. - 9.8 * t
    h = 10. * t - 0.5 * 9.8 * t ** 2

    print*, "La altura y la velocidad son:", v, h
end program
```

Comment: Place a leading left parenthesis (`(`) in the format string at the position indicated.

Comment: I may not know Fortran, but even those that *do* would want to see your code.

Comment: Please actually post the code *in the question* not a screenshot of it.

Comment: This question is like [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32312438) but with output rather than input.

Comment: Do not screenshot the code, post copy it into the question. Others may need to run it and it should be possible to find it using search engines. Also on my screen it is so small that I can't really read it from the picture.

Comment: As people suggest, please paste your code as texts into the Question...

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from this line

```
print "Escribir tiempo:"
```

which should should be corrected as

```
print *, "Escribir tiempo:"
```

The error message seems to arise because gfortran tries to interpret "Escribir..." as a format string, which is the output version of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32312438) (as suggested by @francescalus), so the error message may be a bit mesleading to OP...)

```
program main
    print *, "hi"
    print "yo"
end

$ gfortran test.f90
test.f90:4:10:

     print "yo"
          1
Error: Missing leading left parenthesis in format string at (1)
```